# How to stop a URL connection upon thread interruption Java

Tags: java, multithreading, url

I have a multithreaded program that visits URLs. The threads are run through an executor service, and when the user chooses to quit through the GUI, the program attempts to interrupt the threads by calling `executor.shutdownNow()`. However, it takes a very long time for the program to shut down because many of the threads are blocked in a `url.openStream()` call, and since this does not throw `InterruptedException`, so far I've been forced to just check before and after the call for `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to interrupt a URL connection upon thread interruption? Otherwise, what would be the best approach to let the program shutdown as quickly as possible?

Note that I would prefer not to set a timeout on the connections because I would like all URLs to be visited while the program is still running.

Comment: Looks like Java v16 introduced cancelable futures which might help if you're okay with cancelling the specific HTTP request thread.
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8252515

Comment: Also looks like OkHTTP has added support for listening for thread interruptions:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6611

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Javadocs for [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), it gives you a hint on this: If you call getInputStream or getOutputStream on the URLConnection and then close either of these streams, it will close the connection. If you are stuck waiting on getInput/OutputStream call, then I don't think anything can be done. But if you have the stream, close it (it'll throw an IOException and release any threads waiting on the stream) and the connection is finished

FYI: I have found that this method of closing an InputStream either when you want it to time out or when you just want to stop processing is highly effective, much more so than using interrupt()

Comment: I think the majority of the time is spent waiting on `openConnection()`, and then `getInputStream()`... In fact, it seems more time is spent on the latter. Is there nothing else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Apache HttpClient**

The best thing is to use the Apache HttpClient instead of `URLConnection`. That's a way more advanced client than `URLConnection`, it's easier to use, and it's interruptible. The downside is that it's not included in all Java environments by default, so it can cause an additional dependency that you need to ship with your software. If that's of no concern, then go for it.

**If you have to stick with `URLConnection`**

Nowadays usually HTTP or HTTPS is used for URLs on the network, so your `URLConnection` might actually be of type `HttpURLConnection` or `HttpsURLConnection` respectively. If that's the case, you are lucky. The latter ones have a key advantage over `URLConnection` (see below). First, you need to cast to `HttpURLConnection`. You can do this safely when using HTTP or HTTPS in your URL.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

`HttpURLConnection` has an additional method, `disconnect()`, which you can now use. Calling this method causes the `getInputStream()`, or any threads blocked in `read()` invocations on such a stream, to throw a `SocketException: Socket closed`:

```
conn.disconnect();
```

**Caveat**:
The javadoc gives a contrary idea for `disconnect()`:

> Calling the `disconnect()` method may close the underlying socket if a
>   persistent connection is otherwise idle at that time.

However, I've tested it in JDK1.8 under Ubuntu and on Android and it works nicely and in exactly the same way in both environments, so this sentence in the documentation is actually not true, and maybe it should not be true, because this is the only way to interrupt a `URLConnection`. It even works when both, the client and the server indicate that they can keep-alive the connection and even when there is no "otherwise idle connection".

Comment: Note that `conn.connect()` is not interruptible by `disconnect()`, so here your only option is to set a connect timeout. And you don't get around `connect()`, because it gets called by `getInputStream()` if you don't call it directly in your code.

Comment: Seems like Apache HttpClient isn't interruptible either. `execute` method does not throw `InterruptedException`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **JAX-RS http client**. It supports asynchronous requests. Forgive me using Kotlin, but you do it in Java the same way.

```
//compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.0.1'
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder

val th = Thread {
  val urlString = "http://long.running.page"
  val cli = ClientBuilder.newClient()
  val fut = cli.target(urlString).request().async().get()
  println(fut.get())
}
th.start()
println("wait")
Thread.sleep(3000)
println("interrupt")
th.interrupt()
th.join()
```

After putting a comment to @DanielS answer, I also found examples of [asynchronous clients in Apache library](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-ga/examples.html), using `HttpAsyncClients`. So seems like it supports interruption, but not with `HttpClient` class.

EDIT 2023: After seeing DanSerbyn's comment, I admit, that Jersey doesn't really stop URL connection. Only the future gets cancelled, but the request is proceeding in background. Installing a response callback (an argument to `async.get()`) confirms that. Still a correct response is obtained from the url, if we allow the program to continue.

Comment: I don't think javax.ws.rs throws InterruptedException from the get() method even if it's async. It looks like javax.ws doesn't check for interruptions at all.

Comment: You are right, @DanSerbyn. Interrupted exception comes from Future. If we allow the program to run longer, and install a callback for the request, it still completes. Even with newest jersey client 3.1.4.

Answer (score -3):

The easy answer is to use `System.exit(0)`, which will force all threads to die.

Comment: I don't prefer to use this, since There are other calls that the threads could be blocked in, such as writing to a database, etc, and I need to make sure all the resources are cleaned up.

Comment: Alright, then why not join() all those threads (the non-URLConnection ones), and call exit() once it's just the URLConnection ones left?

Comment: If it's not that simple, then I concede exit() is a poor option.

Comment: hahaha - thank you for the laugh - upvoting...
Might be a good answer though if we're talking about the lambda